System Event ID 3 (FilterManager) caused system to be very slow
The other day my PC suddenly was very slow and laggy, despite being entirely up-to-date and Scannow and Scanhealth returning no problems. The only thing I could find was a few "Event ID 3" instances in The System section of Event Viewer. The lag and slowness started on boot-up, continued all the way through to a shut-down, and then continued in that same way through subsequent restarts. It had sorted itself out by the time I returned to the PC later that day.
The Event reads thus:
Filter Manager failed to attach to volume '\Device\Harddisk1\DR1'.  This volume will be unavailable for filtering until a reboot.  The final status was 0xC03A001C.
With these further details:

System

Provider

[ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager
[ Guid]  {f3c5e28e-63f6-49c7-a204-e48a1bc4b09d}
EventID 3
Version 0
Level 2
Task 0
Opcode 0
Keywords 0x8000000000000000

TimeCreated

[ SystemTime]  2024-09-18T04:12:09.8151698Z
EventRecordID 643766
Correlation

Execution

[ ProcessID]  3676
[ ThreadID]  6816
Channel System
Computer imperfect

Security

[ UserID]  S-1-5-19

EventData
FinalStatus 0xc03a001c
ExtraStringLength 21
ExtraString \Device\Harddisk1\DR1


This has never happened before. Googling seems to suggest it has something to do with backups... but I never use any sort of back-up programmes.
